# Coveralls.io: How to load the gem 'coveralls' when developing a gem itself (not an app)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, code-coverage, coveralls

I want to use [Coveralls.io](https://coveralls.io/) for my gem [Headhunter](https://github.com/jmuheim/headhunter) that I'm developing at the moment. The doc says, I should simply add

```
gem 'coveralls', require: false
```

to the project, but as far as I know, this isn't the right way to load gems within another gem. Instead, stuff like that should happen in the `.gemspec` file. So I tried to add it like this:

```
s.add_development_dependency('coveralls', '>= 2.0')
```

But this doesn't work - it breaks my gem's whole functionality:

```
$ rake
/Users/josh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/headhunter/css_hunter_spec.rb ./spec/headhunter/css_validator_spec.rb ./spec/headhunter/html_validator_spec.rb
/Users/josh/Documents/Work/MuheimWebdesign/headhunter/lib/headhunter/css_validator.rb:6:in `<class:CssValidator>': undefined method `full_gem_path' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

This is the file that breaks:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'nokogiri/xml'

module Headhunter
  class CssValidator
    VALIDATOR_PATH = Gem.loaded_specs['headhunter'].full_gem_path + '/lib/css-validator/'
```

So `Gem.loaded_specs['headhunter']` isn't available anymore, no idea what's going on here.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

I was wondering the same and I just got it working.

You need to add:

```
spec.add_development_dependency "coveralls", "0.7.0"
```

to your .gemspec (0.7.0 is the coveralls gem latest version as the time of writing this)

make sure to run `bundle install`successfully

and add:

```
require 'coveralls'
Coveralls.wear!
```

to the beginning of your spec_helper.rb or test_helper.rb, before requiring anything else.

Hope this helps.